# Red tags are displaying strangely

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, meta

Got this on Chrome, Mac, 100% zoom:

[image]

Others have apparently been having similar issues with tag display.

Comment: This appears to be something to do with visited - the tags show up as white for pages I haven't previously visited and on hover

Comment: I can confirm this on Opera 12.15, Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now fixed on dev. will be live after the next prod build (within 24hrs).

Answer (score 2):

As Kalina correctly noted, one of the included CSS files, `http://cdn.sstatic.net/gamingmeta/all.css?v=df27b9f4c1d2`, has the following rule overriding the default `moderator-tag` CSS class colouring for visited tag links:

```
.post-tag:visited
{
    color: #666666 !important;
}
```

This needs to be added to the CSS file to fix the issue:

```
.moderator-tag:visited
{
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```